# Does PHP OPcache also cache the file load from file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, opcache

I was not able to find an answer to my question in the docs or by a few hours of googling.

Essentially, it all boils down to whether this code can be cached by OPcache including the `json`  file itself:

```
<?php
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('./test.json'), true);
```

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Also, what makes you think that OPcache caches any data returned by functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, OPcache is only caching you precompiled script in memory so PHP does not need to read and parse it on every page request.

The result of your code, like the response of your file_get_contents()-call, is not cached by OPcache.